# getting asynfileupload controls file name on button click

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using ajaxfileupload control on my asp.net page. After image is uploaded, I call uploadcomplete method to save the image on disk and show in image control using following javascript:

```
  string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(PhotoAFU.FileName.Trim()); // encrypt filename 

                    string filePath = Path.Combine(storagePath, fileName);
                    string fileVirtPath = GetImageUrl(fileName); 

       int rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(1, 1000);
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(PhotoAFU, PhotoAFU.GetType(), "img",
                        String.Format(
                            @"top.document.getElementById('{0}').src='{1}?x={2}';
                            top.document.getElementById('{3}').value = '{4}'",
                            EditPhotoImage.ClientID,
                            fileVirtPath,
                            rnd,
                            UploadedImageFileNameHF.ClientID,
                            fileName),
                        true
                );
```

Now I click on a save button and try to get the image using following code:

```
Path.GetFileName(EditPhotoImage.ImageUrl) // shows old image


or


Path.GetFileName(PhotoAFU.FileName) // it shows actual image name not encrypted one
```

but they both show old image not the current image  or actual image name not encrypted name. How can I get the filename from above method in this method ? I tried using viewstate but it is not working properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass data from server to client in `PostedUrl` property of `AjaxFileUploadEventArgs` parameter in `UploadComplete` event handler as JSON obeject and get this data in `OnClientUploadComplete` handler on client side:

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string fileVirtPath = "foobar";

    e.PostedUrl = string.Format("{{ fileName: '{0}', imageSrc: '{1}?x={2}' }}", 
        fileName, fileVirtPath, new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(1, 1000));
}

 function AjaxFileUpload1_OnClientUploadComplete(sender, args) {
      var fileInfo = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(args.get_postedUrl());
      $get("<%= EditPhotoImage.ClientID %>").src = fileInfo.imageSrc;
      $get("<%= UploadedImageFileNameHF.ClientID %>").value = fileInfo.fileName;
 }
```