# AjaxFileUpload: How can I alert the user to a server-side error in OnUploadComplete?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've got the `AjaxFileUpload` control working just fine -- it uploads, and on completion calls the server-side code to move the files around, works just fine, etc etc etc.

What I'm worried about are *potential* server-side errors, and how to hand back some sort of warning to the user. Not an Ajax error, but something on the server-side code.

Now, I've got log4net running just fine, and it's called in my error-trapping code and merrily dumping logs when I hard-code an error.

But that doesn't tell the users anything.

`RegisterStartupScript` doesn't seem to be a valid solution, because there's no PostBack that would allow it to operate (same as my first attempt at populating fields. doh!).

Now, I can shove some JS into the `ClientUploadComplete` or `ClientUploadCompleteAll` to do a PostBack... but that doesn't seem right, and it would require that server-side error-messages be queued-up for display. Plus, it clears out the `AjaxFileUpload` display of what has been uploaded.

All the error-handling I've seen regarding these controls is for Ajax errors.
Is there anything for server-side issues that allows for easy feedback to the user?

Am I even barking up the right trees?

---

**UPDATE** Using the pointers @ [Yuriy's other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743107/getting-asynfileupload-controls-file-name-on-button-click/18761934#18761934) I've got the following working:

Onn the server side:

```
    protected void OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // does something with the uploaded files that _might_ fail
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var ce = Logger.LogError(ex);

            var msg = string.Format("{{ 'id': '{0}', 'message': '{1}'}}",
                 ce.ErrorId, ce.Message);
            e.PostedUrl = msg;
        }
    }
```

(The Logger dumps the complete exception into a log4net log, and returns an error-number and consumer-friendly message to contact support)

Back on the page, the `AjaxFileUpload` control is configured to call the JS when complete:

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload runat="server" ID="Uploader" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10"
OnUploadComplete="OnUploadComplete"
OnClientUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_OnClientUploadComplete"/>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AjaxFileUpload1_OnClientUploadComplete(sender, args) {

        var errText = args.get_postedUrl();
        if (!errText) return; // only process if populated

        var errinfo = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(errText);

        if (errinfo && errinfo.id && errinfo.message) {
            var idEl = document.getElementById('errnbr');
            var msgEl = document.getElementById('errmsg');
            if (idEl && msgEl) {
                idEl.innerHTML = errinfo.id;
                msgEl.innerHTML = errinfo.message;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

which populates the following:

```
<div class="failureNotification" id="ErrorDisplay" runat="server">
    <span id="errnbr"><asp:Literal ID="ErrorNumber" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
    <span id="errmsg"><asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `AjaxFileUploadState` enumeration include `Failed` member I can't find any case where it used.

So there are two solutions available I believe.

The first is to tweak ACT project to add setters to `State` and `StatusMessage` properties of `AjaxFileUploadEventArgs` class and handle values of these properties on client in `raiseUploadComplete` function of [Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.Control](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Server/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.Control.pre.js) class and `onUploadCompleteHandler` of [Sys.Extended.UI.AjaxFileUpload.ProcessorHtml5](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Server/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.ProcessorHtml5.pre.js) class.

Or you can pass custom JSON to client via `AjaxFileUploadEventArgs.PostedUrl` property, deserialize it on client in `OnClientUploadComplete` handler and show error message if any. Please check this question for sample of usage `PostedUrl` property: [getting asynfileupload controls file name on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743107/getting-asynfileupload-controls-file-name-on-button-click/18761934#18761934)

Comment: I working with a variant of the AjaxFileUploadEventArgs.PostedUrl solution. Thanks!