# How to validate file Size in ASP.net AjaxFileUploader

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AjaxFileUploader to upload multiple files in my ASP.net project.

I want to validate File Size before uploading file to 4 MB.

My Code is:

```
 <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload
    id="ajaxUpload1" OnUploadComplete="ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete"
    ThrobberID="MyThrobber1" MaximumNumberOfFiles="5" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="swf,pdf"></ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload>

    <asp:Image id="MyThrobber1" ImageUrl="~/images/loading.gif" Style="display:None" runat="server" />
```

And

```
  protected void ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {

            int fileSize = e.FileSize;

                // fileSize in bytes
                if (fileSize < 4194304)
                {
                    //String currentDir = FileManager1.CurrentDirectory.PhysicalPath;
                    String FilePath = Path.Combine(currentDir, e.FileName);

                    // Save upload file to the file system
                    ajaxUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);

                }

   }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145302/ajaxfileupload-how-can-i-alert-the-user-to-a-server-side-error-in-onuploadcompl/19154482#19154482

Comment: Basically, would be better to tweak this file http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Server/AjaxControlToolkit/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.ProcessorHtml5.pre.js in ACT project to validate file size on client at least in browsers which support HTML5

Answer (score -1):

**Updated Try This:**

```
protected void ajaxUpload1_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
           int fileSize = e.FileSize;

     //String currentDir = FileManager1.CurrentDirectory.PhysicalPath;
      String FilePath = Path.Combine(currentDir, e.FileName);
            // fileSize in bytes
            if (fileSize > 4194304)
            {
             ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "SelectDetails", "alert('You Exceed the limit.');", true);    
              return;

            }
                // Save upload file to the file system
                ajaxUpload1.SaveAs(FilePath);
    }

 catch (Exception ex)    
  {
    throw ex;
  }

}
```

Comment: That i already did, i want to display error message if file size is more than 4 MB